# Unable to show Giphy GIF in Discord chat using robot

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, giphy, giphy-api

I am using Javascript for my Discord bot to make a call to the Giphy Random API Endpoint. But the problem is when I try to get the bot to show the gif in Discord chat, it doesn't show anything. It's just a blank, it doesn't even show the gif URL.

I know it's getting the gif URL because it shows in the log:

```
GET URL BROOOOO: https://giphy.com/gifs/animated-top-icons-dAkW9Z1YuihG0
```

But it just doesn't render it in Discord, as shown [here](https://gyazo.com/1999f42dbef6e4abcdb4140f3122a525). It's blank.

I'm very confused because this is the same URL as the built-in Discord Giphy search capability. (If you type `/giphy <search-terms-here>` it will embed a gif of your choice that follows the same gif URL as the one I'm trying to use.

I must be overlooking something small or doing an easy mistake.

This is the function that makes a call to Giphy:

```
// Function that randomly gets a gif via Giphy Random API Endpoint
const randomGiphy = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(`https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/random?api_key=${process.env.GIPHY_API}&tag=&rating=G`,
        {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
        });
        const myJson = await response.json();
        console.log('json');
        console.log(myJson);
        console.log('data');
        console.log(myJson['data']);
        console.log('data url');
        console.log(myJson['data']['url']);
        console.log(`GET URL BROOOOO: ${myJson['data']['url']}`);
        return myJson['data']['url']; // GIF URL OBTAINED HERE
    }
    catch {
        console.log("couldnt fetch a gif bruh.");
    }
}
```

The code that calls the Giphy API function: (It's the `!gif` command)

```
// Will recognize commands to generate various quotes
client.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.content === 'ping') {
        message.reply('pong');
    }
    else if (message.content === '!dadjoke') {
        var dadJoke = await getDadJoke();
        message.reply(dadJoke);
    }
    else if (message.content === '!happy') {
        message.reply('');
    }
    else if (message.content === '!encourageme') {
        message.reply(getProductivityQuote());
    }
    else if (message.content === '!love') {
        message.reply('');
        var request = "https://webhook.site/836ecfe2-a79f-41df-b5a8-64850105850d";
        try {
            const response = await fetch(request,
            {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                  'Accept': 'application/json'
                },
            });
            const myJson = await response.json();
        }
        catch {
            console.log("couldnt make call to webhook");
        }
    }
    else if (message.content === '!gif') {
        message.reply('getting gif...');
        var gif_url = randomGiphy();
        message.reply(randomGiphy());
    }
    else if (detectBadWords === true ) {
        for (var i = 0; i < forbiddenWords.length; i++) {
            if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes(forbiddenWords[i])) {
                if (message.author.id === client.user.id) return;
                message.reply('Stop cursing or I\'m going to suck your bootyflakes!');
                // message.delete();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You should post the code that does the `console.log` and sends a message to chat.

Comment: Right, my bad! Editing it now...

Comment: Can you send the code that calls the function and sends the message?

Comment: @DaCurse Yup, lemme add it real quick!

Answer (score 0):

`randomGiphy` is an async function so you need to await it like:

```
const gif_url = await randomGiphy();
message.reply(gif_url);
```